# How to set the degree of parallelism used by Powershell Workflow

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, workflow, powershell-3.0

I want to change (increase) the degree of parallelism used by Powershell Workflow (ie. the `workflow` keyword in Powershell 3+). I'm using the `parallel` keyword as well as `foreach -parallel`, but the default degree (5) is not enough.

I've determined the setting I need to change to increase the degree of parallelism is `MaxSessionsPerWorkflow` which can be found on the [New-PSWorkflowExecutionOption](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849862.aspx) cmdlet, however I cannot figure out how to apply that setting to the current console session (ie. what you get when you just start `powershell.exe`).

I've been able to apply that setting to a remoting session by creating a new Session Configuration, then starting a new Session using that Configuration, then running commands in that Session, but that's a horrible solution that requires remoting to be enabled on the machine and to be running as Administrator. ([Here's an example](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/838AA02D/792E7326) of this horrible technique.)

I've tried changing the default `microsoft.powershell.workflow` Session Configuration in the hope that it would affect a standard Powershell console session, but it does not seem to.

How can I set the `MaxSessionsPerWorkflow` setting for a normal powershell.exe console session, without using any remoting?

Comment: you've probably already read: http://www.dupsug.com/?p=101

Comment: @CB. what did that page say? It's 404 now and doesn't seem to be cached in wayback/gcache.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985392/how-do-you-increase-the-number-of-processes-in-parallel-with-powershell-3

Answer (score 0):

I ran across [this article](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Run-Parallel-Parallel-377fd430) on technet by Cookie.Monster as well. It doesn't change the workflow limits but gets around it by using runspaces. Note it is also nice as you can ensure any additional modules only get imported once in the initialsessionstate this can further reduce execution times if you are loading large modules.